# Github actions check_run is not called

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am playing with github actions and trying to do something whenever other check is completed. I see 0 runs for this action.
This action is available in master branch and I am opening PR to the master.

I've tried to capture events via webhooks and I receive events there just fine. Why is my action not working?

Code below:

```
name: on check run 

on:
  check_run:
    types: [ completed, rerequested, completed, requested_action]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: ENV
      run: env
    - name: check out event
      run: cat "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH"
```

*update*
I also tried to have other checks in the repository (travis ci), the action is still not executed.

**update 2**

It turned out I was looking for different event that I needed. I confused status even with "check run" event. Travis ci in it's default setup produced "status" event, "check" api needs to be enabled separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that the GitHub Checks API support on Travis was only added to travis-ci.com. So if your checks are running on travis-ci.org you need to migrate.

See this blog post for the announcement.
https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-07-announcing-support-for-github-checks-api-on-travis-ci-com

> It is available to private and open source projects using travis-ci.com

This is the announcement about migration of 
https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-09-27-deprecating-github-commit-status-api-for-github-apps-managed-repositories

> As part of our gradual migration to GitHub Apps for our GitHub integration, we’re formally deprecating GitHub Commit Status API updates for repositories on travis-ci.com managed by GitHub Apps. Instead, these repositories will have status updates reported to the GitHub Check Runs API.

Comment: it does not work regardless of PR or regular push to master. travis check works just fine after the pus or pr and I wanted to run my github action after the travis is done.

Comment: just to clarify: the travis job has no issues. the GH action is not triggered upon completion of other check (travis in this instance). thanks!

Comment: Yes, I understand that the Travis check itself is working fine. What I was trying to explain is that the reason `check_run` is not executing after the Travis check completes is because that event is not being created. You can see in the screenshot that the checkbox is unchecked. You could try checking it, but I wonder if Travis will revert the change to its settings if it notices it.

Comment: Checking the check run didn't help and I believe it wasn't supposed to.

Comment: The flow in this situation is this push => github calls travis => travis starts a job => travis creates check via github api => {this is when gh action should fire} => travis done => travis completes check via github api => {this is when gh action should fire again}. If I create my own webhook with my own server I receive all these calls for "check runs" from github because of travis. But somehow they don't trigger GH action :( Events that travis is listening to are not related to events that GH action is listening.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining the flow. It sounds like it could be a bug. Might be worth asking GitHub support for help.

Comment: I think I've figured out. Updated the answer.

Comment: huh. I just figured it out myself as well, thanks for your help! it was indeed my misunderstanding of checks api. what the travis was producing for me was actually "status" event, not the "check run". I also tried circleci and enabled check through it's settings. so in the end I've got "cherk run" from circle and "status" update from travis.

Comment: for me check_run always returns success regardless of the outcome. Same with check_suite. Must be a bug